# gauge invariance of the Feynman amplitudes

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, polarization, feynman-diagrams, gauge-invariance, ward-identity

When we calculate the photon polarization sums over amplitudes, 
$$X=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{2}|\mathcal M_r|^2=\mathcal M_\alpha\mathcal M_\beta^*\sum\limits_{r=1}^{2}\epsilon_r^\alpha\epsilon_r^\beta$$
we find it very helpful that we can simply make a substitution:
$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{2}\epsilon_r^\alpha\epsilon_r^\beta\rightarrow-g^{\alpha\beta}$$

This is due to the equality:
$$k^\alpha\mathcal M_\alpha(k)=0$$

Now Franz Mandl and Graham Shaw in their book Quantum Field theory attribute this property as the result of the gauge invariance of QED

> Gauge invariance of the theory implies the gauge invariance of the matrix elements, i.e. of the Feynman amplitudes. ...
>   For any process involving external photons, the Feynman amplitude $\mathcal M$ is of the form$$\mathcal M=\epsilon_{r1}^\alpha(\mathbf k_1)\epsilon_{r2}^\beta(\mathbf k_2)...\mathcal M_{\alpha\beta...}(\mathbf k_1,\mathbf k_2,...),\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(8.30)$$
>   ...
>   The polarization vectors are of course gauge dependent. For example, for a free photon, described in a Lorentz gauge by the plane wave$$A^\mu(x)=const.\epsilon_r^\mu(\mathbf k)e^{\pm ikx}$$
>   THe gauge transformation$$A^\mu(x)\rightarrow A^\mu(x)+\partial^\mu f(x), $$
>   with $$f(x)=\tilde f(k)e^{\pm ikx}$$implies$$\epsilon_r^\mu(\mathbf k)e^{\pm ikx}\rightarrow [\epsilon_r^\mu(\mathbf k)\pm ik^\mu\tilde f(k)]e^{\pm ik^\mu }$$Invariance of the amplitude (8.30) under this transformation requires$$k_1^\alpha\mathcal M_{\alpha\beta...}(\mathbf k_1,\mathbf k_2,...)=k_2^\beta\mathcal M_{\alpha\beta...}(\mathbf k_1,\mathbf k_2,...)=0,$$i.e. when any external photon polarization vector is replaced by the corresponding four-momentum, the amplitude must vanish.

My question is how to understand the statement "**Gauge invariance of the theory implies the gauge invariance of the matrix elements, i.e. of the Feynman amplitudes**",

and **does "the gauge invariance of the matrix elements" really mean that when we make substitution $A^\mu(x)\rightarrow A^\mu(x)+\partial^\mu f(x)$ in the amplitude $\mathcal M$, it will not change**?

I saw in Peskins' book how he spent much argument to prove $k^\alpha\mathcal M_\alpha(k)=0$ using the diagrams, so I wonder whether this argument in Mandl's book is valid.

Anyway, what is the significance of the gauge invariance of QED in this equality $k^\alpha\mathcal M_\alpha(k)=0$?

Comment: What is exactly not clear for you ? If you have one on-shell external photon, with $M = \epsilon^\alpha M_\alpha$, or two on-shell external photons, with $M = \epsilon^\alpha \epsilon^\beta M_{\alpha \beta}$, the physics does not depend on the gauge invariance transformation $\epsilon^\alpha \to \epsilon^\alpha + \lambda k^\alpha$, so you need $k^\alpha M_\alpha =0$ or $k^\alpha M_{\alpha \beta} =0$